# Force ipad to render site in Google Chrome via url parameters or javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ipad, cross-browser, rendering

I am doing a POC whose requirement is quite unique.

We are running SAP netweaver portal 7.3 and the client requires the exact desktop version to be opened in ipad.

Due to rendering issues some portal short links(links to direct application inside the portal rather than the homepage) need to be opened in Chrome and others in Safari. Majority of application is to be opened in Chrome.

For that i have designed a simple HTML page containing hyperlinks to the above mentioned hyperlinks. For Chrome links i use the following-

```
var hname=<host>+"/<app name>";
location.href="googlechrome"+hname.substring(4);
```

is the portal landing page- http://myportal.corporg.net/irj/portal
 is the short link to the app inside the portal.

The final working url is like- http://myportal.corporg.net/irj/portal/myapp

With the googlechrome:// i am able to trigger the link to be opened in Chrome from Safari. But it loads in mobile version.

But this portal does not support mobile versions as per vendor specs and hence throws a compatibility error which is a part of the portal error handling. upon choosing the desktop version, the app starts working.

The requirement is somehow to trigger the desktop version, when the URL is called either via javascript in the bookmark page(the javascript snipped shared above) or via any url parameters.

NOTE-  There can be no change in the device software like rooting etc. These are only ipad air 2 devices.

Restriction- The corporate portal can not be changed as well. We cannot change any codes in the portal as well. it has to be either via javascript or via url parameters.

Is there anyway this can be done

Comment: Why not just do some browser detection and append a stylesheet to fix the rendering issues?

Comment: as i mentioned, i cannot touch the source webpage at all.. it is a jsp provided by vendor so i am not allowed to change the Par file